# How to show Database in DataGridView by monthly

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm developing Point of Sales system.

My problem is: **I need to show my database by monthly** but my code isn't working.

My code is:

```
sql = "select * from POS where iDate = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + "'";
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        dt.Clear();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "to show by monthly"? It's not quite clear what you're doing, could you show an example of your data, what you want to get from it and what you're getting now?

Comment: Could you also define 'not working'?  You aren't getting the result you want? Not getting any results at all?  An exception is occurring?  Complete details will help to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not create your sql queries like that, it's very insecure. Instead use the OleDbCommand constructor. For selecting dates in a specific month/year, you can use DATEPART. Below is something I wrote up real quick, so it's untested. You might have to tweak it a bit.

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbCommand command;

// Create the SelectCommand.
command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM POS " +
                           "WHERE DATEPART(m, iDate) = @Month "+
                           "AND DATEPART(yyyy, iDate) = @Year", con);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", 2);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", 2015);

adapter.SelectCommand = command;
```